# Cannot find function from another file in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

In my file `gpio.c` I have:

```c
#include <modules/comm/module.h>
...
void testing(void)
{
    u8_t buf[] = "lsjdflkdsjf";
    cli_output(buf);
}
```

In `gpio.h` I have:

```c
void testing(void);
```

In `module.c` I have:

```c
#include <drivers/gpio/gpio.h>
...
static void cli_output(u8_t buf[])
{
    printk("hi");
    return 0;
}

static int fg_temp(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    testing();
    return 0;
}
```

In `module.h` I have:

```c
static void cli_output(u8_t buf[]);
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the following error?

```sh
<project dir>/drivers/gpio/gpio.c:108: undefined reference to `cli_output'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My file system is such that `/drivers` and `/modules` are in the same main project directory if that is of any help. Thanks!

Comment: `static void cli_output` Why [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)?

Comment: `static` basically limits the scope of the function to the file it's in. You can't externally link it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `static`. `static` limits the scope of the function to it's own file.

So you get:

In `module.c` I have:

```
#include <drivers/gpio/gpio.h>
...
void cli_output(u8_t buf[])
{
    printk("hi");
    return 0;
}

static int fg_temp(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    testing();
    return 0;
}
```

In `module.h` I have:

```
void cli_output(u8_t buf[]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that static limited the scope so I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

In `module.c`, you define `cli_output()` as `static` function. Refer to [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/static-functions-in-c#:%7E:text=A%20static%20function%20in%20C,keyword%20before%20the%20function%20name.):

> A static function in C is a function that has a scope that is limited
> to its object file. This means that the static function is **only**
> visible in its object file.

So there are 2 scenarios:

## Use `cli_output()` as static function.

If you want to call `cli_output()` only in `module.c`, define it as `static` function, also add function prototype for `cli_output()` in `module.c`:

```c
static void cli_output(u8_t buf[]);
```

Remember to remove the function prototype in `module.h`.

## Use `cli_output()` as global function

Just remove the `static` keyword implemented for both definition and declaration of `cli_output()` in `module.c` and `module.h`.